# Self-adjointness (matrix or operator)

Tags: linear-algebra

There exists a matrix (or operator) is not self adjoint but  $A^*A = A ^ n$ ? for any integer $n>2$

Comment: What's $n$ in this question?

Comment: @Magma n is intger $n>2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the linear operator - $$T:\mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C, \space \space T(x)=ix$$

It is not self adjoint (its eigenvalues are not real). But it is unitary - $$T^*(x)=-ix,\space\space TT^*=T^*T=I$$

Moreover - $T^4=I$, and so $T^*T=T^4$

You can find similar examples for some different choices of operators of the form - $$T_{\theta}(x)=e^{i\theta}x$$
(Different angles will correspond to different values of $n$)

Comment: but its not true for any integer $n>2$

Comment: The first example $T$ holds for $n = 4$. But to find an operator for arbitrary $n$, use $T_\theta(x)$ as given above, where $\theta = 2\pi/n$.